# I am getting Undefined response in node.js for the request as

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am creating simple node.js application , following are the 4 files created .
File1: index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router")
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {}
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
server.start(router.route , handle);
```

FILE2:SERVER.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url")

function start(route, handle)
{
    function onRequest(request,response)
    {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("request for" + pathname + "recieved");

        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});

        var content = route(handle, pathname)
        console.log("Contents Is" + content);

        response.write("Content is " +content);
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888)
    console.log("server has started");
}

exports.start = start;
```

FILE 3:ROUTER.JS

```
function route(handle, pathname)
{
    console.log("About to route a request for" + pathname);

    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function')
    {
       return handle[pathname]();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("No Request handler found for "+ pathname);
        return "404 Not Found";
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

FILE 4:requestHandlers.js

```
function start()
{
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called ");
    return "Hello Start";
}

function upload()
{
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called");
    return "Hello Upload";
}


//This allows us to wire the request handlers into the router, giving our router something to route to
exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

Now when i start index.js on terminal and request http://localhost:8888/start on my browser i am getting output as:

```
$ node index.js
server has started
request for/recieved
About to route a request for/
Request handler 'start' was called 
Contents Isundefined
```

so in server.js line //var content = route(handle, pathname) is not returning proper value "Hello Start" .
i have just started leaning please any one can tell what is wrong ?

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps you made changes to your code and did not restart your server?

Comment: I also confirmed that it works fine.

Comment: Ohhh really , then why the hell i am not getting proper output .. i am using MAC and sublime text . is it some problem?

Comment: Ohh now its started working ....:) i dont know how but tthanks )